# Unable to bootstrap nomad cluster with multi-region setup "Error bootstrapping: Unexpected response code: 500 (No path to region)"

Tags: consul, nomad, hashicorp

I am trying to setup Nomad ACL among a multi region and multi datacenter cluster,
In server stanza I added the below on all server nodes

```
server {
  enabled = true
  bootstrap_expect = 2
  encrypt = "XXX-same-on-all-servers-XXX"
  authoritative_region = "HOME-DC"
  server_join {
    retry_join = ["server1", "server2", "server3"]
  }
}
acl {
  enabled = true
}
```

After I restart all the servers on tailing the logs this is what I get

```
2021-02-01T11:38:04.156Z [WARN]  nomad.rpc: no path found to region: region=HOME-DC
2021-02-01T11:38:04.157Z [ERROR] nomad: failed to fetch namespaces from authoritative region: error="No path to region"
```

And this is I get if I run

```
nomad acl bootstrap -address=$NOMAD_ADDR
Error bootstrapping: Unexpected response code: 500 (No path to region)
```

On the docs I see it asks you to set the replication_token value of the acl stanza, but I am not clear on how to do it, Does it has to be generated somehow like the encrypt token? If yes then how?  [Reference](https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/nomad/access-control-bootstrap?in=nomad/interactive#set-the-authoritative-region)

Answer (score 2):

- authoritative region:  `authoritative_region` is not required and should be removed. After removing it, run `nomad acl bootstrap` will success.
- non-authoritative regions:

  - `authoritative_region` is always required.
  - `replication_token` is required too, `replication_token` could be your authoritative's bootstrap token, or create another token from for less capabilities.

Comment: thank you sssoooo much!! it has helped to  resolve token problems with multi-region federation nomad!

Answer (score 0):

A couple more details about how to make proper nomad configs and acl of multi-region federation nomad.

suppose we have two  distinct nomad clusters (or regions that is basically the same). nomad cluster in region "ovh" and nomad cluster in region "us".

we federate them:

```
$ nomad server join 10.113.151.192:4648 10.113.151.174:4648 10.113.151.231:4648 10.113.151.224:4648  10.113.151.233:4648  10.113.151.90:4648
Joined 6 servers successfully
```

now we need to select primary region. let it be "ovh" region. then we go to the nomad server in "ovh" region and create so called replication token like this:

```
$ nomad acl token create -type="management" -global=true \
  -name="Cluster A Replication Token" \
  -token="b1e55cc6-8289-6b6e-c779-9f0b0a30e96b"
Accessor ID  = d74642e7-2b8b-25c1-d4e9-169e18548788
Secret ID    = 6ca5eae5-adb9-1687-f2f3-214ab5c4f8c5
```

where "-token" is "bootstrap token of ovh region"

now we go to "us" region nomad servers and make some changes like so:

```
# cat /etc/nomad.d/main.json 
{

    "acl": {
        ...
        "replication_token": "6ca5eae5-adb9-1687-f2f3-214ab5c4f8c5"
    },
...
...
  "server": {
        ...
        "authoritative_region": "ovh",
        ...
    },
...
```

so basically we need to add "authoritative_region" and "replication_token" options to config.
restart nomad service on all "us" region servers. (we need to change configs only in "us" region).

The result: go to web ui, authenticate via ovh "bootstrap token". And you can successfully navigate in both regions "ovh" and "us".